# raspberrypi to raspberrypi /bluetooth/errorcode 111, connection refused

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm studying rasp pi3 b+

I want to communication rasp pi - rasp pi  by Bluetooth

already set pair, connect each other in cmd ( a strange situation : (command)scan on >Relative address doesn't appear, but pair add, connect add is a success)

and

I entered the cording as below

```
From Bluetooth import*

client_socket=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
client_socket.connect(("Add , port"))

while True:
      msg = client_socket.recv(1024)
      print("receive msg: {}".format(msg))
client_socket.close()

    enter code here
    enter code here
    enter code here

----------------

another one

same ...
while True:
      msg=raw_input("send")
      print(msg)
      clinet_socket.send(msg)
client_socket.close()
```

after input "python filename.penter code herey " in cmd

error occurred

```
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (111, "connection refused')
```

help me plz...

Comment: Did you literally use `client_socket.connect(("Add , port"))`?

Answer (score 0):

What is the device on the other end of the link?

Does the remote device support RFCOMM or Serial Port Profile (SPP)?

You can see the list of services for the remote device with:

`bluetoothctl info <mac_address_of_remote_Device>`

Comment: 1. Rpi 3B+, another one Rpi 4

Comment: So you are starting the server script on one RPi and then starting the client on the other one? Could you edit your question so it is obvious what code is running on which computer please. Here is a link to a blog about doing something similar http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/